# Access to line arguments in shell script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, script

I wonder if there is possible to access full command line call in shell script. In my script I need to pass it further. I find that there are $@ and $* accessors, but it do not pass all the characters, for example if I write in command line:
`$ my_script xyz -m "something here"`
and in my script I access command line arguments as follows:

> arguments="$*"
>
> echo $arguments

I will see output: `xyz -m something here`. It unfortunately removed quotes, is there possible to keep them? Then I want to pass these arguments to another script, I do not know how many of them will be, and at which position in line I will have quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I actually solve my problem, before, in my first script I fire second script like I wrote above, but actually in my first script I should use:

> second_script "$@"

To fire second script, now it works as expected. Relevant are quotes around $@.